# Why should I disable my broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm developing an app that shall notify the user daily, so it registers an alert that is fired daily. To survive a restart of the device, it registers a broadcast receiver that is called upon system boot as described here:

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#boot

The guide recommends to disable the broadcast receiver if not needed:

> Notice that in the manifest, the boot receiver is set to android:enabled="false". This means that the receiver will not be called unless the application explicitly enables it. This prevents the boot receiver from being called unnecessarily. You can enable a receiver (for example, if the user sets an alarm) as follows:

In my case I disable my broadcast receiver if the user disables notifications and enable it if he changes his mind again.

The question is: **Why should I disable the boot broadcast receiver?** What's so bad about about these unnecessary calls? I mean, they don't hurt and registering and unregistering surely costs time.

**Also, should I disable other broadcast receivers like my alarm receiver if I haven't registered any alarm currently?**

Comment: Because it's generally a bad practice to activate/run unnecessary things as you use resources for nothing (memory, CPU, ...). But yeah nobody's gonna die for sure.

Comment: `What's so bad about about these unnecessary calls? I mean, they don't hurt and registering and unregistering surely costs time.` They may not hurt YOUR app but if a lot of apps use it then it increases boot time if every app has to start up

Comment: On top of the performance issues of too many bootup apps. It's saying that it's good practice to programmatically enable it. I.E., They have to enter the app and do something that enables it meaning they consciously know that the app will start periodically notifying them. If the app was installed, then just started randomly pushing notifications, they may find that really annoying.